# EC2 describeImages then AWS.request won't return anything

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I'm trying to get AMI ImageId with Image name

```
const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15', region: 'us-east-1' });

const params = {
       DryRun:false,
       Filters: [
           {
                Name: 'name',
                Values: [
                    'linux-amz-1-*'
                ]
            },
            {
              Name: 'State',
              Values: [
                'available'
              ]
            }   
        ]
    }
const request = await ec2.describeImages(params);
```

This will return a request object which data is null, and doesn't contain imageId or imageName. I'm not sure if this step already wrong.

```
await request.on('success', function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }).on('error', function(error, response) {
          console.log("error");
        });
request.send();
```

Then I did this and it doesn't log anything at all.

I tried to replace the params with imageId to test it and I got same result.

```
const params = {
          ImageIds: [
              "ami-0b86e9ebc05359ccd"
           ]
     }
```

Comment: asterisk will not work, it will be treated as a string. Try with the most basic one to check the function is working or not. Refer the [documentation].(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeImages-property).

Comment: Hi Lamanus, I already tried it with imageId which also not work const params = {
          ImageIds: [
              "ami-0b86e9ebc05359ccd"
           ]
     }